# Date-Time-Range Picker in Angular 5

Tags: datetime, angular5

Currently implementing an angular 5 app and need to Incorporate a Date-Time-Range picker. Looking at some library which strictly does not use BootStrap or Jquery. Something using Angular Material will be ideal.

Any suggestions will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use/extend this custom date-range-picker:

https://github.com/Bigless27/date-range-picker

The only dependency seems to be the moment library.

See this video on how it was created: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovamx9ePIuE